# $(this.element) is undefined, don't understand why

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, this

Hey everyone I'm trying to add a class to the target element clicked using jquery's event delegation method but the '$(this.element)' is undefined. Why is that? Thanks guys!!!

```
  tabWrapper.on('click', '.services-tabs', function(event) {
    $('.services-tabs').removeClass('selected');
    $(this.element).addClass('selected');
    console.log(this.element);
  });
```

Comment: It's just `$(this)`, not `$(this.element)`

Comment: use only `this` instead `this.element`

Comment: OMG so stupid! Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Reference for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in the jQuery API documentation says:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events
>   this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events this is an element matching `selector`. (Note that this may not
>   be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant
>   element.) **To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be
>   used with jQuery methods, use `$( this )`.**

Of course, nothing prevents you from doing `$(this.element)` but it won't work unless `this` has a property called `element` that happens to be a DOM node (or a string with HTML).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be $(this) instead of what you have here:

```
$(this.element)
```

Try this:

```
tabWrapper.on('click', '.services-tabs', function(event) {
    $('.services-tabs').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    console.log(this.element);
  });
```

EDIT: I see this has already been answered in comments by @RoryMcCrossan